# C iteration up to a very large number - compiler warning about unsigned int

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning, unsigned-integer

I have the following piece of code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define POWER 10000000000000000000

int main()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < POWER; i++)
    {
         ....
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and the [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc) compiler gives me the following warnings :

> ex1.c:33:19: warning: integer constant is so large that it is unsigned [enabled by default]
>   ex1.c:33:2: warning: this decimal constant is unsigned only in ISO C90 [enabled by default]

How can I iterate with `i` running through all the values until it reaches `POWER`? I tried declaring `i` as `unsigned int` but the warnings remain.

Comment: do you really want to loop `10000000000000000000` times? `for (long i = 0; ; i++)` will, technically, do the same (infinite loop)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I am trying to iterate through very large numbers so yes, I need to loop so many times.

Comment: `#define POWER 10000000000000000000` -->> `#define POWER 10000000000000000000ULL` and `int i;` -->> `unsigned long long i;`

Comment: @Marievi: it'll require huge amount of time, *years* at least

Comment: @joop Thank you so much! My compile problem is solved :)

Comment: What is `it` in "I tried declaring it as `unsigned int` but the warnings remain."  Is `it` the variable `i` or the constant `POWER`?

Comment: I don't understand the close votes. I get the same warnings when I compile the code in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your constant `10000000000000000000` requires 64 bits to represent it. In hexadecimal, it's `0x8ac7230489e80000`. It can be represented in an *unsigned* 64-bit type, but not in a *signed* 64-bit type.

As of C99, all integer constants are of some signed type: the first of `int`, `long int`, or `long long int` in which the value will fit.

C90 (which didn't yet have `long long int`) had different rules. In C90, an unsuffixed decimal integer constant is of type `int`, `long int`, or `unsigned long int`.

gcc's default mode is `-std=gnu90`, which supports the C90 standard plus GNU-specific extensions.  If you're on a 64-bit system, `long` and `unsigned  long` is 64 bits. Under C90 rules, your constant is of type `unsigned long` (assuming `unsigned long` is at least 64 bits). Under C99 and later rules, assuming there's no integer type wider than 64 bits, it's a constraint violation. (gcc version 5 changed the default to `-std=gnu11`.)

The compiler, which apparently is operating under C90 rules, is warning you that the meaning of `10000000000000000000` differs depending on which edition of the standard the compiler is operating under.

You can make your program "work" with the following changes:

```
#define POWER 10000000000000000000ULL // suffix to specify the type
...
for (unsigned long long = 0; i < POWER; i ++)
...
```

But although that makes the program valid, it doesn't make it practical. At one iteration per nanosecond, it will take more than 3 centuries for that loop to finish. My own reasonably modern computer executes one iteration of an *empty* `for` loop in about 1.6 nanoseconds. Whatever problem you're trying to solve, I suggest either finding a different way to solve it, or reducing it to a smaller problem. The fastest way to execute that loop is to wait a few decades for hardware to become faster and *then* compile and execute it.

(This assumes the body of the loop is non-trivial. If the body of the loop does nothing, the compiler might optimize away the loop altogether.)

Comment: "Under C90 rules, your constant is of type unsigned long". Are you sure about this? In C++, a decimal literal is never converted to an unsigned type. I'm not quite so sure in C though.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Yes, I'm sure. I just checked my copy of the C90 standard (ISO/IEC 9899:1990 (E)).

Comment: `#define POWER 10000000000000000000U`  is sufficient.  (LL not needed).  LL has a minor disadvantage on say a platform with 128-bit `unsigned long long` and the LL would unnecessarily make the constant that larger type.

Comment: BTW, correct me if I'm wrong, but GCC has recently switched to `gnu11` as the default dialect.

Comment: @AnT: Yes, as of version 5. But a lot of distributions still use older versions by default. If you care, you should specify the version explicitly with `-std=...`.

Answer (score -1):

The value `10000000000000000000` (= 10^19 if i counted right) needs 64 bits for to be allocated, this is 8 bytes. You are getting a warning because the type `int` uses 4 bytes and therefore it cannot store that number. With `unsigned int` you double the maximum positive number you can store but it is 4,294,967,295 wich is still not enough. If you want to use `int` you could use iterated loops.

```
    for(i=0;i<p;i++){
        for(j=0;j<p;j++){
            for(k=0<p;k++){
            /*loop*/
            }
        }
     }
```

Where p would be an `int` or `unsigned int`with the vaue of the cubic root of POWER (In this case the cubic root is not valid as 19%3 != 0 and p would not be an `int` , its more of an idea than an actual solution)

Comment: "You are getting a warning because the type `int` uses 4 bytes and therefore it cannot store that number"  --> No.  Warning is occurring because `10000000000000000000` cannot fit in `long long`. (C99) or in `unsigned long` (C90).  The range of `int` is not the issue.